# finding length in java

Tags: java, math

Question:
(Geometry: distance of two points) Write a program that prompts the user to enter
two points (x1, y1) and (x2, y2) and displays their distance between them.

The formula for computing the distance is 2(x2 - x1)
2 + (y2 - y1)
2
. Note that
you can use Math.pow(a, 0.5) to compute 2a. Here is a sample run:

Here is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Southpaw

{
  public static void main(String [] args)
  {

    double x1;
    double x2; 
    double y1; 
    double y2;
    Scanner length = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.println("Enter x1 and y1");
      x1= length.nextDouble();
      y1= length.nextDouble();

      System.out.println("Enter x2 and y2");
      x2= length.nextDouble();
      y2= length.nextDouble();

     System.out.println ((x2 - x1) + (y2 - y1));
   }
 }
```

Can you explain how to do the equation? And how to write the program?

Thanks!

Comment: You should probably use the formula provided instead of just printing the sum of the x and y distances.

Comment: im stuck with the equation im using this System.out.println Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x2 - x1, 2) + Math.pow(y2 - y1, 2)); and it says i need a semicolon in the beginning of Math(error need semicolon).sqrt which makes no sense.

Comment: you can have missing semicolon anywhere above the place the error was detected (at least that is my experience but as I am not JAVA coder it can be different in JAVA) the only semicolon I am missing is after the `class { ... };` btw `pow` is a bit overkill for `Math.sqrt(((x2-x1)*(x2-x1))+((y2-y1)*(y2-y1)));`

Answer (score 0):

The equation would look something like:

```
double distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x2 - x1, 2) + Math.pow(y2 - y1, 2));
System.out.println(distance);
```

Comment: Using the 'Hint' it would be `Math.pow(Math.pow(x2 - x1, 2) + Math.pow(y2 - y1, 2), 0.5);`

Comment: Hey so the code above is the same, its mainly the equation yes.

Comment: Here is the equation that im using now and its saying error System.out.println Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x2 - x1, 2) + Math.pow(y2 - y1, 2)); right in the beginning of Math(error).sqrt and the error is having a semicolon but that makes no sense. and when i do add it in, it just leads to more errors

Comment: Do you have parentheses around System.out.println();?

Comment: it works this time with your editted code yeah, however when i do enter the x2,x1 y2,y1 values it still gives me a flat answer of 0.0

Comment: oh wait i think since im using "double" i have to get a decimal answer or else it terminates. i just tried with decimals and i got a realistic decimal answer. how do i do it if i dont want decimals? just add int instead of double?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying. Your code works ok for me now.